# Value of a public int is not getting saved in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm calling a method called as ext method(s), at the end of this method int n is not able to save its value, int n has been publically defined

```
void extMethod(String s){
    DatabaseReference db99 = firebaseDatabase.getReference(s);
    db99.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            temp = dataSnapshot.child("sList").getValue().toString();


            n = 0;

            lm = temp.split(",");
            for (e = 0; e <= lm.length - 1; e++) {
                if (lm[e].equals(tData[7])) {
                    n = 1;
                    showToast("if "+lm[e]+"="+tData[7]);

                } else {
                    showToast("else "+lm[e]+"="+tData[7]);
                    n1 = 2;


                }

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

Even the value of temp which has been publically declared is not having its value after the end of this method, am I missing something?

any inputs would be helpful

Comment: are your sure code is entering in this condition to set value of n and temp is assigned any value? Try to apply Logs and debug then

Comment: @UsmanRana,tried everything,logs,toast and also a method to write the value to file in storage,right after the OnDataChange,the value changes to 0 and temp changes to null :|

Comment: try to make them static variables to make it sure that values are not overridden somewhere

Comment: @UsmanRana Tried that as well,the only thing that works is if i do all the operations inside the OnDataChange method itself,the strange thing is,i have like 4 other methods based on this  example and those seem to work without any problem :|

Comment: Check snapshot whether it is null before setting its value to temp. like.. `if(dataSnapshot!=null){temp = dataSnaphot.getValue ....}`

Comment: @JerinAMathews It's not,like i said,i'm able to write the value onto a file and also show the value onto a toast,but only inside OnDataChange,strange thing is i've implemented similar things and those instances are working fine